# Why is function running even though its specified for only certain viewport width?

Tags: javascript, html, function, event-handling

I'm trying to only run a hover function when viewport is above 1400px but for some reason it works when page is loaded under 1400px, but not when it is resized from a width > 1400px to below 1400px.

This is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/emilyyyyyyyyy/pen/ZEVbxYM). Why is the hovermenuFn running when the window is resized??

```js
const body = document.querySelector("body");
const headerNav = document.querySelector(".header");
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
const menuListItems = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-list-item");
const menuListItemsWithChildren = document.querySelectorAll(
  ".menu-list-item.menu-item-has-children"
);
const breakpoint = 1400;

// Hover 
let hoverMenuFn = () => {
  let width = window.innerWidth;
  if (width <= breakpoint) {
    return false;
  } else {
    menuListItemsWithChildren.forEach((menuItem) => {
      menuItem.addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {
        console.log("mouse enter desktop");
        menuItem.classList.add("open");
        menuItem.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "true");

        // Close other dropdowns
        const otherMenuItems = document.querySelectorAll(".open");
        otherMenuItems.forEach((otherMenuItem) => {
          if (otherMenuItem !== event.target) {
            otherMenuItem.classList.remove("open");
          }
        });
      });
      menuItem.addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
        console.log("mouse leave");
        menuItem.classList.remove("open");
        menuItem.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
      });
    });
  }
};

hoverMenuFn();

// Menu item click
let clickFunction = () => {
  document
    .querySelectorAll(".menu-item-has-children .menu-link-level-1")
    .forEach((menuItem) => {
      menuItem.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        console.log("click menu");
        const parent = menuItem.parentNode;
        const isOpen = parent.classList.contains("open");

        if (!isOpen) {
          parent.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "true");
          parent.classList.add("open");
        } else {
          parent.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
          parent.classList.remove("open");
        }

        event.preventDefault();

        // Close other dropdowns
        const otherMenuItems = document.querySelectorAll(
          ".open .menu-link-level-1"
        );
        otherMenuItems.forEach((otherMenuItem) => {
          if (otherMenuItem !== event.target) {
            otherMenuItem.parentNode.classList.remove("open");
          }
        });
      });
    });
};

// Mobile Navigation
let mobileNavFn = () => {
  clickFunction();
  let width = window.innerWidth;
  console.log(width);
  if (width <= breakpoint) {
    console.log("resized to mob");
    headerNav.classList.add("mobile");
    body.classList.add("scrolled");
    if (!menu.classList.contains("menu--opened")) {
      menuListItems.forEach((menuListItem) => {
        menuListItem.classList.add("hide");
        menuListItem.classList.remove("show");
      });
    }
  } else if (width >= breakpoint) {
    console.log("resized to desktop");
    headerNav.classList.remove("mobile");
    body.classList.remove("scrolled");
    menuListItems.forEach((menuListItem) => {
      menuListItem.classList.add("show");
      menuListItem.classList.remove("hide");
    });
  }
};

mobileNavFn();

// Add event listeners for window resize and scroll
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  mobileNavFn();
  hoverMenuFn();
});
```

```css
.menu-list-item {
 width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 3px solid pink;
  margin-bottom: 40px
;
}

.open {
  background: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-list-item menu-item-has-children">Item</div>
    <div class="menu-list-item menu-item-has-children">Item</div>
    <div class="menu-list-item menu-item-has-children">Item</div>
    <div class="menu-list-item menu-item-has-children">Item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Once you have added an event listener, it will stay added unless you call removeEventListener..

Comment: Instead of adding event listeners conditionally, just have all the listener functions check the width, and return if it's less than `breakpoint`.

Comment: The alternative is that `hoverMenuFn()` must remove all the event listeners that it added.